# ctrl-C doesn't work after calling second new_event_loop()

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I can't kill the program below with ctrl-C:

```py
import asyncio

loop1 = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop1)

loop2 = asyncio.new_event_loop()

loop1.run_forever()
```

However, I can kill the program below:

```py
import asyncio

# execute this first
loop2 = asyncio.new_event_loop()

loop1 = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop1)

loop1.run_forever()
```

Why?

(I'm running these in python 3.11.1, windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

neither of these methods is a proper way to construct an event loop, and both ways should be avoided, the official way to start an eventloop is to use [asyncio.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run) with a coroutine.

the behavior you are seeing is because asyncio sets the current signal handler to the file-descriptor that interrupts the last created loop using [signal.set_wakeup_fd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.set_wakeup_fd), so the interrupt signal is sent to loop 2, while loop 1 is being served by the process and isn't handling those signals the OS is sending, you can read more about the way asyncio handles keyboard interrupt in [Handling Keyboard Interruption](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#handling-keyboard-interruption)

to avoid all of these problems you should use the official way to start an event-loop, ie : `asyncio.run(main())` as in the [asyncio documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html) and avoid creating loops yourself, otherwise you can run into all sorts of trouble. (orphaned tasks, bad file descriptors, unhandled signals, etc..) or just avoid creating more than one eventloop, and handle all the related consequences of creating a loop yourself.

> Application developers should typically use the high-level asyncio
> functions, such as asyncio.run(), and should rarely need to reference
> the loop object or call its methods. This section is intended mostly
> for authors of lower-level code, libraries, and frameworks, who need
> finer control over the event loop behavior.

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    print('Hello ...')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('... World!')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: I read your old answer (before edit), which said this problem is windows-specific. Actually I tried my code in WSL Ubuntu and it works (I could kill both the programs). But anyway you edited your answer, so I guess that's because this problem might happen even in some linux environments. maybe?

Comment: @mehee https://bugs.python.org/issue23057 , you can depend on it not happening on linux, but not so for the other problems creating a loop yourself will make.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the link. I couldn't find it. So it's too tricky for me to handle the raw eventloops... FYI, I ran into the problem while trying codes in [aiosmtpd](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd/blob/master/examples/basic/server.py).